# Updating image on sunset/sunrise

Tags: javascript

Okay guys, I got a page, displaying 24/7, I got sunrise/sunset time that I'm getting from server (websockets, there is much more data, lets stick to this) and I got images of sun/moon.

What is the best way to change image on page, depending on daytime?

The point is: when image updating function should be called? Each day I should get new values, but I can't predict the time when I'll get those. If I will use delayed timers, how should I get timers updated, when I will recieve new sunrise/sunset time?

Comment: Daytime of your server or of your users ?

Comment: A simple `if` statement should suffice: `if (currentTime >= suriseTime && currentTime < sunsetTime) img.src = 'sunriseSrc'; else img.src = 'sunsetSrc';`

Comment: @KevinLabécot Both server and clients are in the same building, so doesn't really matter ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Timers.  You can set a relative timeout by first determining what time it is, and using the offset to sunrise/sunset.

Comment: okay, which event i should create timer on? Notice that each day, sunset/sunrise time is changing

Comment: Actually, I realized, what should I do here. I will set timeout, when previous sunset/sunrise happened, and on value change, I will cancel current timeout, setting a new one. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think you can create a timer on your page which check the time of day every period of time (10 minutes) and compare it with the dates you got from server.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

setInterval(check_dates,60000);

});

function check_dates()
{

var now = new Date();
if(now>=sunrise_datetime && now< sunset_datetime)
{
$('body').html('<img src='sunrise_image.jpg' />');
}
else
{
$('body').html('<img src='sunset_image.jpg' />');
}

}
```

Comment: I thought of it, and it already works, but I'm looking for something more elegant